# Clunk over speed bumps when cold

Tags: mazda, control, three, arm, clunk

I have posted about this before but have recently just replaced some parts so thought I’d ask again.

Hit a bump too fast last December and since then when hitting speed bumps I get a clunk at the rear. When the weather is warm it is much quieter and tends to be worse in the mornings first drive or so. Then gets better during the day.

I have had top mounts, shock absorber, end links and sway bar bushing done but noise is still there.
Pretty much leaves the control arms, issue is there are 3 at either side on the rear of the car. So before spending more money, is it a chance that I cracked a control arm bushing and now that’s why it clunks when cold ?

Thanks